# Opendaylight Openflow accepted Cipher Suits and TLS Version

Tags: ssl, opendaylight, openflow

I'm looking in Opendaylight for the file or setting where you can specify the accepted cipher suits and TLS versions for Openflow.

For the RESTconf interface this is the `custom.properties` file under `/etc/` with my sample entries:

```
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.protocols.included=TLSv1.3
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.ciphersuites.included=TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,etc.
```

But where can I find the same for the Openflow interface?

In the `legacy-openflow-connection-config.xml` under `/etc/opendaylight/datastore/initial/config/` where I also specified my keystore and truststore with the certificates, it doesn't seem to work or?